# Flutter back navigation doesnt trigger RouteAware didPop()

Tags: flutter, dart

My goal is to track routes being presented and dismissed for analytics purposes like described on this article: [https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-track-screen-transitions-in-flutter-with-routeobserver-733984a90dea](http://medium)

I am pushing a `CupertinoPageRoute` and passing a Widget to it that implements the `RouteAware` Mixin.

```
final RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();
return CupertinoApp(
    ...
    navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
}
```

Pushing like so:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyWidget()),
);
```

The Widget

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with RouteAware {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {
    print('never called');
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    print('never called');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          CupertinoNavigationBar(
            middle: Text('42'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `didPop()` method is never called when popping a `CupertinoPageRoute` with the back button unless I push with `rootNavigator = true` which is not what I want.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**: This behavior only happens when pushing routes from a CupertinoTabView, as it creates a new nested navigator.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64677)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the final solution shown in the Medium article does not extend every `StatefulWidget` with `RouteAware`. Instead, it extents its own implementation of a `RouteObserver` to get notified about every route change.

Using this approach, you should be able to insert your custom `RouteObserver` into both you main App as well as your `CupertinoTabView` to achieve what you need.